# Boy from Earth who later finds out he can teleport accused for the murder of the leader of another planet

Tags: story-identification, books, young-adult, space, teleportation

A boy is arrested for the murder of some important leader of a planet. He is transported to space using multi-dimensional teleportation or something.
I think he might be kidnapped at some point by space pirates?

There are few people who can find little holes in the universe and make them into portals, thereby teleporting. The person who commits this murder has this ability and has the face of the boy.

At the end of the book boy realises he also has this ability.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  When did you read this?  Do you remember the names of any of the characters or the places they visit?  Was this a hardcover, paperback or an e-book?  What did the cover art look like?

Answer (score 2):

This might be *Space Crime Conspiracy* by Gareth P. Jones. A plot summary from Google Books follows because the book is not on Internet Archive.

> In prison, accused of murdering President Vorlunar, things are not looking good for Stanley. But when he is released, matters get even worse! He discovers that his assumed crime has given him not only notoriety, but value.
> How can a boy who lives above a pub in south-east London cope with bounty hunters with beards on their foreheads, lawyers who specialise in Intergalactic Law, Pan-Dimensional Litigation and Criminal Prosecution, and the terrifying bird-headed space pirates, the Marauding Picaroons.